# No sound with \a in cygwin

Tags: c, windows, cygwin

I'm doing some coding using cygwin with c programming. There is no sound with `\a`. Do I have to install some packages? There is no problem with `cl` compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\a");

    return 0;
}
```

with the following setting

`gcc test.c -o fun.exe`

Comment: Please post your sample code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RSahu, it is just one line `printf("\a")`

Comment: downvoting with suggesting to close the post without leaving a comment. Following this concept, no one will be able to improve his/her post.

Comment: I didn't downvote but you will be better off posting your code, no matter how small or trivial it may seem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess that it has something to do with the terminal emulator you are using. I am using `mintty`. When I edit the options, I am able to specify the behavior of "Bell".

[image]

When uncheck "Sound" I don't hear anything. When I check "Sound", I hear a beep.

Comment: PERFECT ANSWER. thanks. But the sound is not beep.